# Rails gsub not working in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub

I have the following code in my view, I don't understand why the gsub doesn't work.

`<div class="section" id="<%= section.title.gsub(/_/, ' ') %>">`

When `.title = "Test Title"` it just returns `"Test Title"` rather than `"Test_Title"`

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the other way around:

```
"Test Title".gsub(/ /, '_') #=> "Test_Title"
```